# Type of parameter or return type as parameter?

Tags: scala

I am currently in a project where I need to learn Scala and Lift, so I am reading Beginning Scala atm. Everything went fine until I reached the method declaration, in which it has these confusing line of code

```
def list[T](p : T): List[T] = p::nil
list:[T](T)List[T]
```

Author wrote that this is pretty obvious, but... help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line `def list[T](p : T): List[T] = p::Nil` defines a method named `list` which takes a argument of type parameter `T` and returns an output of type `List[T]` by creating a list using `p::Nil`.

The second line `list:[T](p:T)List[T]` shows the method signature, which again implies the same.

If you try `def list[T](p : T): List[T] = p::Nil` in scala repl you get `list:[T](p:T)List[T]`.